# How can I style a date created by php and output within a single span element

Tags: php, css, smarty

My issue is the CMS I am working with outputs the date within a single span element like so: M/d/Y, which outputs the following html: Mar/03/14.

I would like to style the date to stack onto of each variable 
     e.g. 2014 (on the bottom), JAN (ontop of the year), and 14 (the day ontop of the month).

Unfortunately I only have access to the css and smarty tpl files, not the php files. I am looking for CSS solution but I am open to JS as well.

Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: i dont know of any css alone solution that can actually accomplish that, however its perfectly possible with js. is the date element have an id or some selector you can use?

Comment: the default set by the cmd has it formatted like so: <span class="date">{$templateconf.txtadded} {$item.DateDisplay[0]}</span>  but I can change this and I am also open to ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I writed this example using jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    // You can change for your classes or add this in your smarty template
    var month = $('.month'),
        day = $('.day'),
        year = $('.year'),
        out = $('.out');

    var months = {
        'JAN': '01'
        'FEB', '02',
        'MAR': '03' 
        // etc...
    };

    // Hides the unecessary elements
    month.hide();
    year.hide();
    day.hide();

    out.html(months[month.text()] + '/' + day.text() + '/' + year.text());

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response!  I am a little confused on how to use this script...I posted the line of code above for reference.  Any explanation would be appreciated

Comment: This script will hide your actual structure and create a new one with the contents of your elements of month, year and day. All you need to do is complete the months object, replace the classes .month, .day, .year and .out by your elements (your code will be useful here, so I can give you a real example) and put this code on your page

Comment: My issue is that I can't select the individual elements i.e.. month, day, year.  My code is like this:  <span class="date">{$templateconf.txtadded} {$item.DateDisplay[0]}</span>.

Comment: Oh sorry, I don't understood your question. Well, you can do the opposite. Something like this:

https://gist.github.com/sergiovilar/10000178

The rest you can do with some CSS:
http://line25.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-cool-blog-post-date-icon-with-css